# Gradient Transparent Background

Tags: android, background, gradient

I want to get a transparent gradient over the image, why does transparency work:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.twick.screens.custom.SquaredImageView
        android:id="@+id/rv_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/office"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80abcdef" > //TRANSPARENT WORK
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and so there is no

```
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_blue_indigo>//TRANSPARENT NOT WORK
```

background_gradient_blue_indigo :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:endColor="#800055FA" //80 transaprent
    android:startColor="#807942DF" //80 transparent/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Thx, is worked!

Comment: Yep, accepted!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:alpha=0.8` (or whatever float value you want) along with `android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_blue_indigo"` to the `FrameLayout`.

However, please note that this will make the whole view transparent, not the drawable in the background.

Comment: This makes the whole view transparent though, not only the background.

Comment: I agree. Added that into the answer. :)